# How to get the response of an http website withing a string using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, parsing

How to get the response of an http website within a string? Whatever it was an xml, JSON, html ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call.

you can get the http status code with the `status` property on the xhr.  You can get the actual response text in the `responseText` property.